# Sending mail to multiple Users in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, email, laravel-5

below is my code to send a mail to multiple users.

```
 $email_id =  User::select('email_id')->get()->pluck('email_id');

     Mail::send('mail', [], function($message) use ($email_id)
        {
            $message->to($email_id)->subject('Welcome!!!');
        });
```

I m getting the values in `$email_id` as

```
 ["xyz@abc.com","abc@abc.com","qwerty@abc.com"]
```

With this I get error of

> `Illegal Offset Type`.

But when I write explicitly as

```
$email_id = ["xyz@abc.com","abc@abc.com","qwerty@abc.com"];
```

then I am able to send mail to multiple users.

Why is it not working for

```
$email_id=  User::select('email_id')->get()->pluck('email_id');
```

and is working fine for

```
$email_id = ["xyz@abc.com","abc@abc.com","qwerty@abc.com"];
```

Any help would be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

If we want to send only one email at a time. then we can use this code

```
   $email_id = User::select('email_id')->get()->pluck('email_id'); 
     Mail::send('test', array('user' => $email_id) , function ($message) { 
     $message->from('from@example.com'), 'From Example Name'); 
     $message->to('xyz@gmail.com')->subject('Welcome!!!'); 
})
```

If we want to send an email to multiple users , then we can use this code

```
$email_id = User::select('email')->get()->pluck('email')->toArray(); 
Mail::send('test', array('user' => $email_id) , function ($message) use 
($email_id) { $message->from('from@example.com'), 'From Example Name');
 $message->to($email_id)->subject('Welcome!!!'); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply append

```
->toArray()
```

function to the code.

```
$email_id=  User::select('email_id')->get()->pluck('email_id')->toArray();
```

Note: sending mails this way may create bottleneck on the server and eventually force all mails to be delivered to spam/junk folder (if it ever gets delivered). To avoid this, write a function that will queue all mails. Refer to https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/mail#queueing-mail for better clarification.